# Why does the value of the number not match

Tags: javascript

```typescript
const MAX_VAL = 9_999_999_999_999_999;
const withValueLimit = (inputObj: any) => {
  const { value } = inputObj;
  console.log(`${value} < ${MAX_VAL} == ${value <= MAX_VAL}`)
  if (value <= MAX_VAL) return true;
  return false;
};
```

`MAX_VAL` evaluates to `10_000_000_000_000_000`

I know that value that I entered is greater than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`
but I need to make a comparison, and to not allow values like `MAX_VAL+0.1` and higher

Is it possible to manage that?

Comment: Try to convert string to number and then use <= operator.

Comment: Use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Because there are limitations over string and number, you should replace all non numeric characters and then compare I believe that will work fine.

Comment: "*I know that value is greater than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER*" - seems like you already know what the issue is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that value that I entered is greater than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`...

That's the problem. The literal `9_999_999_999_999_999` actually defines the number value `10,000,000,000,000,000`, not `9,999,999,999,999,999`:

```js
console.log((9_999_999_999_999_999).toLocaleString());
// => "10,000,000,000,000,000"
```

You just cannot reliably work with numbers in that range using the `number` type. (Or rather, they're reliable, but not precise anymore; at that scale, only even numbers [multiples of 2] can be represented. At even larger scales, only multiples of four. Etc.)

For integer numbers beyond the `number` range, you can use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
const MAX_VAL = 9_999_999_999_999_999n;
const withValueLimit = (inputObj/*: any*/) => {
    let { value } = inputObj;
    if (typeof value === "number") {
        value = BigInt(value);
    }
    // console.log(`${value} < ${MAX_VAL} == ${value <= MAX_VAL}`)
    return value <= MAX_VAL;
};
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 1n}));                       // true - valid BigInt
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 10_000_000_000_000_000n}));  // false - invalid BigInt
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 100_000_000_000_000_000}));  // false - invalid number
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 47}));                       // true - valid number
```

In that example, I've allowed the object to either have a `number` or `BigInt` as `value`.

If you need to support obsolete JavaScript engines that don't have `BigInt`, you can use any of several "big number" libraries that were developed for the purpose. (Just search for "JavaScript big number".)

---

In a comment you've mentioned getting this error:

> RangeError: 25.5 can't be converted to BIGINT because it's not an integer

I should have thought of that case. You can handle it with `Math.round`, `Math.floor`, or `Math.ceil` to convert the fractional number to an integer value for the purposes of the check. For instance, if you want to round up (25.5 => 26) in order to perform the check, you'd use `Math.ceil`:

```
const withValueLimit = (inputObj/*: any*/) => {
    let { value } = inputObj;
    if (typeof value === "number") {
        value = BigInt(Math.ceil(value));
        //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    // console.log(`${value} < ${MAX_VAL} == ${value <= MAX_VAL}`)
    return value <= MAX_VAL;
};
```

```js
const MAX_VAL = 9_999_999_999_999_999n;
const withValueLimit = (inputObj/*: any*/) => {
    let { value } = inputObj;
    if (typeof value === "number") {
        value = BigInt(Math.ceil(value));
        //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    // console.log(`${value} < ${MAX_VAL} == ${value <= MAX_VAL}`)
    return value <= MAX_VAL;
};
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 1n}));                       // true - valid BigInt
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 10_000_000_000_000_000n}));  // false - invalid BigInt
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 100_000_000_000_000_000}));  // false - invalid number
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 47}));                       // true - valid number
console.log(withValueLimit({value: 25.5}));                     // true - valid number
```

Given the scale of value you're dealing with, it really doesn't matter which one of those you use; **any** `number` value with a fractional portion is in range (since anything approaching the limit is already at the level of imprecision that fractional values can't be represented).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll mark this as a solution because it works, but it didn't help me because in the code where this function is used, I get `RangeError: 25.5 can't be converted to BIGINT because it's not an integer`

Comment: @RheinmetallSkorpion - I should have thought of that. I've added to the end of the answer.